# how to call a query string while poping up window using JS in 2008 visual studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to pop up an **aspx** page with passing query string in `vb.net` in 2008 VS using `registerrstrtuscript` but still I am not able to access the apsx page:

```
     strJavascript = "window.showModalDialog('../url?user='& userid ,"
                        strJavascript = strJavascript & "'','dialogWidth:650px;dialogHeight:425px;"
                        strJavascript = strJavascript & "status:no;help:no;scroll:no')"
     page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "user detials", strJavascript, True)
```

Comment: Look at the value of `strJavascript` to make sure it is what you want: I suspect you wanted the value of the variable `userid` in there instead of the text "userid".

Comment: Yes I am sending  value to the user ID, but I am not able to get the pop window, is there any another way to call the pop up window?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `strJavascript = "window.showModalDialog('../url?user=" & userid & "',"`?

Comment: I have to try like you said